# How do you map nanopore fast5 files?

Tags: read-mapping, nanopore, fast5

Is there a best practices for mapping Oxford Nanopore files to a reference?

Is there a tool that can take a tarball of fast5 files and map them directly or do they need to be converted to fastq first?

Answer (score 2):

Fast5 files need to be converted to fastq first prior to mapping. There are currently no tools available to map the entire raw signal directly to a reference, although a few tools are available for identifying short sequences within the raw signal.